# Deleting SharePoint File with UpdateListItems Returns Success But File Remains

Tags: c#, sharepoint, whitespace, listitem, delete-file

I am able to Update list items successfully but when I try to delete an item I get the following response:

```
InnerXml = "<Result ID=\"1,Delete\"  xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode></Result>"
InnerText = "0x00000000"
```

This would seem to indicate success, but the file remains!

Here is the code: (The code is the same for editing an existing item, except where noted)
The variables:

```
pID = The SharePoint ID of the list item document.
pFileName = The passed in filename (e.g.: "John Doe Capital.pdf"
pInternalID = An internal ID that is combined with the document in SharePoint (e.g.: 1187)

string lListName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharepointPipelineDocsList"];
XmlNode lSharePointListName = mSharepointListsService.GetList(lListName);
string lListID = lSharePointListName.Attributes["ID"].Value;   // Provides the GUID id for the actual list

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");

string strBatch = string.Empty;

// Construct file url - this is only used with DELETE
string lFileName = StripExtensionFromFile(pFileName);  // Private method that strips off extension.
lFileName = pInternalID + "-" + lFileName;
string lUrlPrefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharepointPipelinesiteUrl"];
string lDestinationUrl = lUrlPrefix
    + "/" + lListName
    + "/" + lFileName;

// Indicate file to be deleted.  This is only used with DELETE
strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>" +
        "<Field Name='ID'>" + pID + "</Field>" +
        "<Field Name='FileRef'>" + lDestinationUrl + "</Field></Method>";

elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
XmlNode ndReturn = mSharepointListsService.UpdateListItems(lListID, elBatch);
```

I read that the Delete command requires both the Document ID value as well as the file url.  I am convinced the problem must be with the CAML.  The is an example value for strBatch:

```
strBatch    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'><Field Name='ID'>980</Field><Field Name='FileRef'>http://intranetdev/finops/Investment Documents/1187-Test - 4</Field></Method>"
```

Perhaps it is the whitespace in the file url?

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a good one. I'd just like to introduce you to a more Sharepoint centered site in the Stack Exchange: [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also why are you deleting like that? Since you've gone down to code, why not just simply get a reference to your item, then `item.Delete()`?

Comment: Hi Renan.  I'll try that.  I already had the code for updating items - and had it working.  In all the references for that web method it also said to use this to add and delete items.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?  I'm stuck on an the exact same problem!